# How can I make the Javascript VM instance names more meaningful in the Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Chrome DevTools with some Node.js apps that are launched with the `--inspect` switch. The Javascript VM instance names all display **Node.js file:///**. Is there a way I can make DevTools display a more meaningful name, or the actual file name?

[image: Chrome DevTools]

I'm running node.js 15 on Windows 10. Launching with `node --inspect=xxxx filename`.

Comment: Are you running with `node --inspect path-to-file.js`? For me it works correctly, showing the path. And what version of Node and what platform are you on?

Comment: I was using `node --inspect file-name`. I've added `.js` on the end and am now getting names based on the file path - `node --inspect file-name.js`.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if that's a bug somewhere in the inspect code or in Chrome's integration that assumes a `.js` extension even though Node doesn't need that